# Incomplete stack trace information

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

For some reason when a NullReferenceException is thrown the stack trace only points to the `throw;` line in the stack trace, and doesn't include the line in the try block where the exception was thrown. Shouldn't this try catch block preserve the stacktrace? The catch block in some obscure case throws a NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on a (quasi) production server.

As I understand it a `try{doSomething();}catch(Exception){throw;}` statement should preserve the stack trace.

```cs
try
{
   Int32 fallbackLCID = 2057; // Default to English for missing translations (was: (await _personalisationRepository.GetOrganisationById(ec.OrganisationId)).LCID)
   HRo.Data.KeyConcept kc = await _localizationRepository.GetKeyConcept(keyConceptId, originalValues, fallbackLCID, ec, token);
   keyConcept = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Domain.KeyConcept>(kc);

   // When there are only key concepts, other system texts or comments in the system text's value, replace them
   if (NeedsFacadeTagReplacement(keyConcept.Value))
      keyConcept.Value = await ReplaceFacadeTags(keyConcept.Value, ec, token);
}
catch (Exception)
{
#if DEBUG
   return new KeyConcept { Id = 0, Value = String.Format("!- KEY CONCEPT: {0} -!", keyConceptId) };
#else
   throw;
#endif
}
```

The first line in the stack trace (from the top) is HRo.Domain.LocalizationFacade.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\Dll-projects\Model\Facade\LocalizationFacade.cs:line 148
Line 148 is the throw statement above. Why doesn't the stacktrace provide information about where in the try block the exception was thrown?

Full stack trace:

```c
at HRo.Domain.LocalizationFacade.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\Dll-projects\Model\Facade\LocalizationFacade.cs:line 148
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at HRo.Domain.LocalizationFacade.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\Dll-projects\Model\Facade\LocalizationFacade.cs:line 119
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at HRo.Util.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func) in C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\Dll-projects\Foundation\Util\AsyncHelper.cs:line 26
at HelperMethods.Infrastructure.CustomHelpers.GetKeyConcept(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Int32 keyConceptId) in C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\WebUI\HRoHelpers\CustomHelpers.cs:line 0
at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LayoutPublic_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\hro-test\hro.accept\Views\Shared\_LayoutPublic.cshtml:line 9
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__0(TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

The code runs under Asp.Net 4.7

Comment: Are you in `DEBUG` mode

Comment: No I'm on a release build which I can't use Debug mode on, and I don't know how to reproduce the exception either. @HasanEmrahSüngü

Comment: Do you have any `async void` signature methods where you can not await but can throw?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the following lines? I guess one of them should be the exception root:

1. C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\Dll-projects\Model\Facade\LocalizationFacade.cs:line 119
2. C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\Dll-projects\Foundation\Util\AsyncHelper.cs:line 26
3. C:\Source\Repos\UIDeploy\WebUI\HRoHelpers\CustomHelpers.cs:line 0
4. c:\inetpub\wwwroot\hro-test\hro.accept\Views\Shared_LayoutPublic.cshtml:line 9